# What should we name the General Chat Room?

Tags: discussion, chat

On Bitcoin.SE it's called "mempool".
On Etherium.SE it was called "Whisper".

Does anyone have any suggestions for a name for the Cardano general chat room?

Comment: I suggest we call it “sciecne” (misspelling intended)

Comment: Suggesting the name of a scientist, specialized in Linguistics (which is related to chat and communication) and with his works on language syntax and theory of parsing grammars: I'd suggest "Chomsky". Though it may be considered political...

Comment: I like the name suggestions, but why not just stick to what works, and call it general chat room? Do we really need a fany name and meaning for something as simple as a chat room?  Most of us don't like to "hang" in there anyway.  It's just my opinion...

Comment: @IvoG This question was aimed at the people who ***do*** like to "hang" in the chat room. For those people, the name of the room does make an impact on their everyday experience. For example, I love hanging around "at the h-bar" on Physics.SE, and I can also very easily find the room on Google (or now by typing "hba.." and letting my browser complete the rest for me based on cache). "General chat room" will not work because the chat rooms across the entire network of ~200 sites are all listed in one place when you click "all rooms". If they were **all** named General Chat Room it wouldn't work

Comment: @Nike Dattani. I agree, it was a silly comment from me. I just wanted to express my opinion about the question. I realice it was wrong of me. Thank you.

Comment: @IvoG no problem :)

Comment: @EkadhSingh could you give your suggestion as an answer, so that we can comment on it and vote on it in comparison to the other answer?

Comment: @StephaneRolland Can you also suggest "Chomsky" in an answer so that we can vote on it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Loveplace" - It will distinguish it from the smallest denomination of ADA if that is an issue.

Comment: I ***love*** it !!!

Comment: This is brilliant

Answer (score 7):

I suggest naming it "Lovelace" after Cardano's smallest denomination because it will be a place for small-talk and is well known by the whole community.

Comment: I love this because it would also serve as a tribute to Ada Lovelace.

Answer (score 1):

'Playground' comes to mind as it is used elsewhere in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting "Chomsky", the name of a scientist, specialized in Linguistics (which is related to chat and communication) and with his works on language syntax and theory of parsing grammars. Though it may also be considered political...

That being said, I consider that "General Chat Room" would still be a perfect valid name suggestion as the semantic is not blurred at all compared to its purpose ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest naming it “sciecne” because Cardano is based off of research papers. However, calling it “science” would be a bit bland, hence “sciecne.” One possible downside of this is we might get confused with another stack exchange.

Comment: Nah mang this is confusing as hell XD